# Redirect URL via User Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I would like to know how I would take the user's input and use it to redirect them to a new URL. For example if the user entered "556859" into the input field and clicked "Go" it would take them to www.website.com/556859.

I'm using ruby on rails but am not sure how to achieve my goal. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use simple javascript to do this, get the value from input element and use this line `window.location=window.location.href +<User Input Value>;`. And what did you try ?

Comment: I've tried taking the examples from the rails website and modifying them but don't know how to do it (code wise) and although people have posted code snippets I do not know how to put them together.

Answer (score 0):

If you need examples for the view and the rest as well, then ask. But this controller method should be enough to point you in the right direction:

```
def redirect_action
    redirect_to "/#{params[:redirect_path]}"
end
```

Comment: I understand the theory of it (taking user input and redirecting it) but I'm having trouble finding the code online or trying to figure it out myself so any examples would be really useful.

Comment: That will work but it's best to avoid string interpolation when you can use the path helpers that your routes generate, e.g. `redirect_to :my_action, params` or `redirect_to my_resource_path(params[:redirect_id])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can send user input to controller method
and in that method you can use redirect_to helper method

For example

in view create form with action="controller/redirect"

and in controller create method redirect
and with params[] use your input

Best regards

Comment: it would be useful. ive tried about 15 different ways and none of them work.

Comment: because you must know how work ruby and rails as well

Answer (score 0):

You'd do something like this:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def redirect
      redirect_to root_path + param
   end
end

#config/routes.rb
post "", to: "application#redirect", as: :redirect

#app/views/application/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag redirect_path do %>
   <%= f.input :param %>  
   <%= f.submit "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

--

The next question becomes "why?"

Rails' routing infrastructure is such that it should give you the ability to access individual views for what you're trying to accomplish.

For example, if you're trying to show `users` in that redirect, you can do:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
    def show
       @user = User.find params[:id]
    end
end
```

This will give you the ability to access `http://yoururl.com/users/12312321`

Alternatively, you could also (if you had nothing else on that part of the app), do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, path: "" #-> http://yoururl.com/12313123
```

If you know what type of data you're trying to show, it should give us more to work with in regards how you'd construct routing structure for it.